# HTML Format in sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I formatted sp_send_dbmail to send email in HTML format. But it is sending the mail with HTML code.

Below is the code I used

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients=N'*****@********.com', 
@body= '<font color="green" face="arial"><i>
Testing<br /> </i></font><hr />',  
@subject = 'SQL Server Trigger Mail', 
@profile_name = 'DBMailProfile1'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to specify `@body_format = 'HTML'` too. The default is `TEXT`.

See [sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) on MSDN: there are HTML examples too