# SQL Server : HTML Format in sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sp-send-dbmail

I'm using this query to send daily reports. What changes should I make to the code to get the output in html format?

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @profile_name = 'DBMAIL',
     @recipients = 'aa@xyz.com',
     @query = 'Select Country, CompanyName, round(sum(TotalSale), 0) as Sale, count(*) as DownloadedCount from PW.dbo.SalesReport group by Country, CompanyName order by Country',
     @subject = 'Daily Sales Report' ;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @profile_name = 'DBMAIL',
     @recipients = 'aa@xyz.com',
     @query = 'Select Country,ltrim(rtrim([Store Name])) as Store, round(sum(TotalSale), 0) as Sale, space(3), max(Convert(varchar(10), LastTime, 108)) as [Last update Time] from PW.dbo.SalesReport where len(Country) > 1 group by Country, [Store Name] order by Country, [Store Name]',
     @subject = 'Daily Sales Detail'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341730/html-format-in-sp-send-dbmail

Answer (score 0):

If you would just [quickly consult the official MSDN documentation on sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) - you would *easily* see this:

> [ @body_format= ] 'body_format'
>
> Is the format of the message body. The parameter is of type varchar(20), with a default of NULL. When specified, the headers of the outgoing message are set to indicate that the message body has the specified format. The parameter may contain one of the following values:
>
> TEXT
>   HTML
>
> Defaults to TEXT.

So just add

```
@body_format = 'HTML'
```

to your calls and you should get the HTML format you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this but it does not make any changes to the results displayed. I was looking to display results in rows and columns.

Comment: @JOJO: well, this just sets the type of e-mail to HTML - but it *doesn't* magically turn your rows and columns into a HTML table. This now allows you to use HTML in your e-mail - but it's **up to YOU** to actually format and create that HTML to use in the e-mail, of course!

Comment: Marc can you help me to modify it to get a tabular result

Comment: I did the formatting and works perfectly. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @Jojo: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.