# sp_send_dbmail sending HTML instead of HTML formatted email

Tags: html, sql-server, t-sql, email

To begin, I have reviewed the following question and incorporated it into my problem: [HTML Format in sp_send_dbmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341730/html-format-in-sp-send-dbmail)

I am trying to dynamically build an email that would send to separate people if needed.  It appears that my string builds just find and sends the email.  The issue is that the email just appears as text that looks like HTML.  Here is my SQL:

```
        HTML_CTE ( EmailRecipients, EmailSubject, EmailBody )
          AS ( SELECT   Strings.Email AS EmailRecipients ,
                        'NOTIFICATION: You have exceeded the alloted meal amount' AS EmailSubject ,
                        N'<HTML>
                        <HEAD>
                            <STYLE>
                                TD {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:11pt;}
                            </STYLE>
                        </HEAD>
                        <BODY>
                            <H3>' + Strings.PersonName + N',</H3>
                            <br/>
                            <p> On the following dates you spent the indicated amounts:</p>
                            <br/>
                            <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>
                                <TR>
                                    <TD>Date</TD>
                                    <TD></TD>
                                    <TD>Amount</TD>
                                </TR>'
                                + Strings.Exceptions + 
                            N'</table>
                            <p>You will see $' + CAST(Strings.TotalOver AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + N' deducted from your paycheck. </p>
                        </BODY>
                        </HTML>' AS EmailBody
               FROM     AllDataStrings_CTE Strings
             )
    SELECT  @ExecSQL = ( SELECT N'EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail'
                                + N' @profile_name = ''GrillExceptions'''
                                + N' ,@recipients = '''
                                + HTML_CTE.EmailRecipients + N''''
                                + N' ,@subject = ''' + HTML_CTE.EmailSubject
                                + N'''' + N' ,@body = ''' + HTML_CTE.EmailBody
                                + N'''' + N' ,@body_format = ''HTML''; '
                         FROM   HTML_CTE
                       FOR
                         XML PATH('')
                       );
SELECT  @ExecSQL;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @ExecSQL;
```

There are a couple CTE's above that build up the table and get the correct data.  The string that is output from the final SELECT is:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'GrillExceptions',
    @recipients = '*******@******.com',
    @subject = 'NOTIFICATION: You have exceeded the alloted meal amount',
    @body = '&lt;HTML&gt;&#x0D;       &lt;HEAD&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;STYLE&gt;&#x0D;         TD {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:11pt;}&#x0D;        &lt;/STYLE&gt;&#x0D;       &lt;/HEAD&gt;&#x0D;       &lt;BODY&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;H3&gt;James Shinevar,&lt;/H3&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;br/&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;p&gt; On the following dates you spent the indicated amounts:&lt;/p&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;br/&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0&gt;&#x0D;         &lt;TR&gt;&#x0D;          &lt;TD&gt;Date&lt;/TD&gt;&#x0D;          &lt;TD&gt;&lt;/TD&gt;&#x0D;          &lt;TD&gt;Amount&lt;/TD&gt;&#x0D;         &lt;/TR&gt;&lt;TR&gt;&lt;TD&gt;2016-11-22&lt;/TD&gt;&lt;TD&gt;&amp;#x20;&lt;/TD&gt;&lt;TD&gt;8.50&lt;/TD&gt;&lt;/TR&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;p&gt;You will see $0.50 deducted from your paycheck. &lt;/p&gt;&#x0D;       &lt;/BODY&gt;&#x0D;                         &lt;/HTML&gt;',
    @body_format = 'HTML';
```

And this results in the following being sent in the body of an email:

```
<HTML> <HEAD> <STYLE> TD {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:11pt;} </STYLE> </HEAD> <BODY> <H3>***** *****,</H3> <br/> <p> On the following dates you spent the indicated amounts:</p> <br/> <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0> <TR> <TD>Date</TD> <TD></TD> <TD>Amount</TD> </TR><TR><TD>2016-11-22</TD><TD>&#x20;</TD><TD>8.50</TD></TR></table> <p>You will see $0.50 deducted from your paycheck. </p> </BODY> </HTML>
```

The above code looks like this in Outlook:
[image]

I have checked and ensured that I am receiving other HTML formatted email.  This issue is not that my email client is set for plain text.  Any ideas or assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the `@body` argument is already HTML-encoded, so that's why you're getting HTML in the e-mail.  Your use of `FOR XML PATH` is the culprit, as it is doing this encoding you don't need.  Find a better approach to building  `@ExecSQL` - I think you're overcomplicating it.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'GrillExceptions',
    @recipients = '*******@******.com',
    @subject = 'NOTIFICATION: You have exceeded the alloted meal amount',
    @body = '&lt;HTML&gt;&#x0D;       &lt;HEAD&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;STYLE&gt;&#x0D;         TD {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:11pt;}&#x0D;        &lt;/STYLE&gt;&#x0D;       &lt;/HEAD&gt;&#x0D;       &lt;BODY&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;H3&gt;James Shinevar,&lt;/H3&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;br/&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;p&gt; On the following dates you spent the indicated amounts:&lt;/p&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;br/&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0&gt;&#x0D;         &lt;TR&gt;&#x0D;          &lt;TD&gt;Date&lt;/TD&gt;&#x0D;          &lt;TD&gt;&lt;/TD&gt;&#x0D;          &lt;TD&gt;Amount&lt;/TD&gt;&#x0D;         &lt;/TR&gt;&lt;TR&gt;&lt;TD&gt;2016-11-22&lt;/TD&gt;&lt;TD&gt;&amp;#x20;&lt;/TD&gt;&lt;TD&gt;8.50&lt;/TD&gt;&lt;/TR&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&#x0D;        &lt;p&gt;You will see $0.50 deducted from your paycheck. &lt;/p&gt;&#x0D;       &lt;/BODY&gt;&#x0D;                         &lt;/HTML&gt;',
    @body_format = 'HTML';
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, I'm just trying to make it so there would be one long string of multiple EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail statements.  That way if there were multiple people who showed up in the extract they would each get an email and I could just send it from one query.  Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Select your CTE into defined variables, then use them to send the email.

Comment: Simplify.  Loop through your source table using a cursor, and just make one call per e-mail address.  Call `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` within the body of the cursor; there will be no need to build a string statement (`@ExecSql`) because you can use `EXEC` directly.  It will be easier to debug, and I promise that the SQL Police won't show up on your doorstep.

Comment: Ok, I was attempting to avoid using a CURSOR at all costs, but if I must, I will.  I'm assuming that this is one of those situations where there really just isn't a good way to do this using set logic and you need the flow of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite your solution into set based and xml based solution instead of dynamic sql.

Your problem is probably in @body - you send whole html into html body:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
            </body>
       </html>
    </body>
</html>
```

You should use div or table tags.